# How do I find multiple strings in a text file?

Tags: python-3.x, macos

I need all the strings found in the text file to be found and capitalized. I have found out how to find the string but getting multiple is my issue if you can help me print, where the given string is throughout my code, would be great thanks.

```
import os
import subprocess

i = 1
string1 = 'biscuit eater'

# opens the text file

# if this is the path where my file resides, f will become an absolute path to it
f = os.path.expanduser("/users/acarroll55277/documents/Notes/new_myfile.txt")

# with this form of open, the wile will automatically close when exiting the code block
txtfile = open (f, 'r')

# print(f.read()) to print the text document in terminal
# this sets variables flag and index to 0

flag = 0
index = 0

# looks through the file line by line
for line in txtfile:
    index += 1

#checking if the sting is in the line or not
    if string1 in line:
        flag = 1
        break 
# checking condition for sting found or not
if flag == 0:
    print('string ' + string1 + ' not found')
else:
    print('string ' + string1 + ' found in line ' + str(index))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your approach would work, but it is very verbose and not very Pythonic. Try this out:

```
import os, subprocess

string1 = 'biscuit eater'

with open(os.path.expanduser("/users/acarroll55277/documents/Notes/new_myfile.txt"), 'r+') as fptr:

    matches = list()
    [matches.append(i) for i, line in enumerate(fptr.readlines()) if string1 in line.strip()]
    fptr.read().replace(string1, string1.title())

    if len(matches) == 0: print(f"string {string1} not found")

    [print(f"string {string1} found in line {i}") for i in matches]
```

This will now print out a message for *every* occurrence of your string in the file. In addition, the file is handled safely and closed automatically at the end of the script thanks to the `with` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but could you possible explain it a bit more so that I can use this in the future?

Comment: Could you explain why we use 'r' or 'r+' when opening the file? also what is fptr? what does ".append" do? explain what enumerate is and why you used it? and what does "in line.strip()" do?  otherwise I think I understand the rest of it thanks again

Comment: Yep - so the first thing you should read up on are ```with``` statements - basically they create a temporary variable that goes out of scope at the end. It is very commonly used when opening files. Next, I used a list comprehension, which is basically a one-line for loop. Using the special ```enumerate``` function in python, each line of the file is automatically assigned an index *i* that we can save. The ```replace``` function automatically goes through and replaces all occurences of your string with a new one. Finally, I used f-strings to do string interpolation, rather than the + strategy

Comment: *r* opens a file in READ-ONLY mode, meaning you can't make changes to it. *r+*, on the other hand, opens the file in read AND write mode, allowing you to read from it and make changes - see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-text-files-python/) for a full list. ```ftpr``` is a variable of type "file descriptor". I always name my variable fptr bc it works just like a file pointer in C/C++. Line.strip() is just to santize our input - it gets rid of non-alphanumeric characters (except spaces) when comparing each string

Comment: Thanks! I will be sure to read up on all of this stuff. And thanks again for taking the time to explain and help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `str.replace-method`. So in the line where you find the string, write `line.replace(string1, string1.upper(), 1)`. The last `1` is there to only make the function replace 1 occurence of the string.

Either that or you read the text file as a string and use the `replace`-method on that entire string. That saves you the trouble of trying to find the occurence manually. In that case, you can write

```
txtfile = open(f, 'r')
content = txtfile.read()
content = content.replace(string1, string1.upper())
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/acarroll55277/Documents/Python_Scripts/TXTFILES.py", line 13, in <module>
    content = f.read()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'                                            This is the error I get. Before when I used print(f.read()) it actually print it so I don't know what the problem is. Do I need to import something?

Comment: Sorry, try to write `txtfile.read()` instead, since `txtfile` is the file handle of course. I've edited my post.

Comment: Thats ok thanks for the reply and help! Buuuut it still doesn't work

Comment: You are right. `str.replace` returns the new string, so it has to be saved as the `content`-variable again... and the `1` should not be there if all occurences are to be replaced.

Comment: I am going to use mr. victors post above but thanks for giving it a try